# svchost.exe в windows 10 засоряет процессы

Tags: windows, windows-10, вирусы

Доброго всем времени суток. Недавно заметил что svchost в процессах очень сильно загружает систему и выглядит подозрительно. Есть кстати момент когда после запуска игры, я банально не могу ее свернуть, после alt+tab вся система просто зависает, но диалог в скайпе продолжается. Получается что у меня просто застывает экран, скорее всего это связано именно с svchost, ну мне так кажется. Можете подсказать, как решить эту проблему? 
Проверял систему Касперским, не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Windows 10 я поставил часа 3 назад. Поставил все драйвера и программы. Система по идее чистая. Вот что я устанавливал. Все с офф сайтов, без танцев с бубнами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это скорее всего обновления скачиваются, проверьте.

Comment: @АлександрСемикашев, нет, все обновления выполняются в контексте одного процесса ```svchost.exe```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальная ситуация. `svchost.exe` является хостом для сервисов Windows, причём во многих случаях один процесс `svchost.exe` запускает единственный сервис.

Проверить, какие сервисы принадлежат конкретному процессу `svchost.exe` можно при помощи [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896653).

[image: Process Explorer]

Попробуйте проверить тем же Process Explorer, какой из сервисов нагружает процессор, а потом отключайте его и смотрите, как изменилось поведение системы. Также есть смысл посмотреть в мониторе ресурсов `perfmon.exe`, может кто сильно нагружает дисковую подсистему.